# PHP string != Variable = 'string'

Tags: php, html

Not sure how to name this question but I am looking for feedback to why when I set a variable to some string it will not let me call that variable in a function... For example:

```
$name = "name";
$quote_name = "'".$name."'";

//echo of $name = name
//echo of $quote_name = 'name'
```

PHP will not allow me to call:

```
if($value['name'] == $quote_name){...}
```

Or

```
if($value['name'] == '$name'){...}
```

But it WILL allow me to call (with the whole function):

```
foreach($question_set_p1 as $key => $value) {
    if($value['name'] == 'name') {
        $first = $key;
        break;
    }
}


$data =  array_filter($question_set_p1, function($arr){ 
    return $arr['name'] == 'name'; 
});
```

Why does PHP allow me to call the string but not the variable?
Is there a way that I can state the variable and not the actual string?

Comment: Because `'name'` doesn't equal `name`?

Comment: `$quote_name = "'".$name."'";` - why not just do `$quote_name = $name;` and quote it in your SQL, which I'm under the impression you want to use this for. `'".$name."'` is used for that. `... VALUES ('".$name."')` or `... VALUES ('".$quote_name."')` depending on what you want to use as a variable. Don't try and re-invent the wheel, *as it were*.

Comment: Are you getting an error, or is your `if` not evaluating to `true`.  (BTW your `if` won't evaluate to `true`....)

Comment: *"Unclear what you're asking"* - is leading by a nose.

Comment: What is setting `$value['name']`?

Comment: If you want to know why this is an issue, you should call `var_dump()` on each of your variables. It will show you the type of variable, in many cases the length of the variable and what is the actual value of the variable. The function is used for debugging. You can visually compare the variables and see why they are different.

Comment: Have done that and they are identical.

Comment: I think I see part of the issue here. If the variable is defined outside of a function, the variable is not available inside the function. This is because of function scope. There are several answers covering this topic. It's not like javascript where global variables are available pretty much everywhere. You need to explicitly call `global $varName` inside of the function in order to make it available to that one function. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: variable is not outside the function

Answer (score 2):

Remove quote in second var, like this:

```
$name = "name";
$quote_name = $name;

if($value['name'] == $quote_name){...}
```

Comment: I don't understand the need to create a second variable with the same value. Why not just `if($value['name'] == $name){...}`?

Comment: @stackoverflow what's var_dump() of `$value['name']` ?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn to treat variable with another function, for example

Answer (score 1):

suppose

```
$value['name'] = 'abcd';
$name = 'abcd';
$quot_name = " ' ".$name." ' ";//(as you entered).
```

Now if you echo `$quot_name` it will return 'abcd' (with quotes) and if you echo `$value['name']` it will return abcd (without quotes).

Therefore `$quot_name` should be `$name` (without quotes) or you should add quotes to `$value['name']` too.